# How to solve error "ORA:01-006 :bind variable does not exist" when working with bind variables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql, error-handling

I have a table with below structure and data :

```
create table TEST_TABLE
(
  item_number NUMBER,
  item_name   VARCHAR2(50),
  item_col    VARCHAR2(50),
  item_pol    VARCHAR2(50)
)
```

Sample data:

```
item_number |  item_name|  item_col |  item_pol
------------------------------------------------
     1      |   blue    |     b     |   c
     2      |   red     |     d     |   a
     3      |   black   |     e     |   a
     4      |   yellow  |     d     |   b
```

This is my sample procedure with in which I'm trying to use `bind variables` .

```
create or replace procedure test_bind_variable(res         out sys_refcursor,
                                               item_number varchar2,
                                               item_name   varchar2,
                                               item_col    varchar2,
                                               item_pol    varchar2) is

  qry varchar2(8000);

begin

  qry := 'select * from test_table where 1=1 ';

  if (item_number is not null) then
    qry := qry || ' and item_number = :1  ';
  end if;

  if (item_name is not null) then
    qry := qry || ' and item_name = :2 ';
  end if;

  if (item_col is not null) then
    qry := qry || ' and item_col= :3 ';
  end if;

  if (item_pol is not null) then
    qry := qry || ' and item_pol = :4 ';
  end if;

  dbms_output.put_line(qry);

  open res for  qry
    using item_number, item_name, item_col, item_pol;

end;
```

The problem is that when all Input parameters have a values , the procedure works properly , without any error , but when only one or two parameters have value , I receive this error : `ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist,`. How can I solve this problem? Some parameters might have value and some may not .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can completely avoid dynamic SQL (you also should never name PL/SQL variables the same as table columns):

```
create or replace procedure test_bind_variable(res         out sys_refcursor,
                                               p_item_number varchar2,
                                               p_item_name   varchar2,
                                               p_item_col    varchar2,
                                               p_item_pol    varchar2) is

  qry varchar2(8000);

begin

  open res for select * from test_table where
    (p_item_number is null or p_item_number = item_number) and
    (p_item_name is null or p_item_name = item_name) and
    (p_item_col is null or p_item_col = item_col) and
    (p_item_pol is null or p_item_pol = item_pol)

end;
```

PS. Make sure you take the operator precedence into account, unlike me.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer , I have a question in here , when we do not provide input parameter "p_item_number" , the original query is this?? --> 

"select * from test_table where
    p_item_number is null or p_item_number = null " ??, I mean what is the exact query when we do not provide the input parameters ?

Comment: I'm a bit (just a bit) confused about this part of query when parameter is not supplied ,
p_item_number is null or p_item_number = item_number, is it p_item_number is null or p_item_number = null ?? how is this always true??

Comment: You can not call a procedure with fewer parameters than defined, not if you did not specify defaults anyway. So "not provided" here means "is null".

Comment: Note that this will cause difficulty for the optimizer as it will have to produce a plan which is legal in all circumstances (a full table scan is the only possibility). Dynamic SQL is recommended for these sorts of requirements.

Comment: @AndrewSayer citation needed

Comment: @mustaccio Demo here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=97f0fb9c732d31d7f4480584c2ee272b As you can see, even hinting it to use an index will not help. I'll admit there is a possibility for an or expansion transformation, but you're not going to get it with 4 different ORs without doing it yourself.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically send bind variables to the dynamic query. Instead, you'll have to code in the bind variables in the same order no matter what, you can use a trick so that they're ignored though.

```
create or replace procedure test_bind_variable(res         out sys_refcursor,
                                               item_number varchar2,
                                               item_name   varchar2,
                                               item_col    varchar2,
                                               item_pol    varchar2) is

  qry varchar2(8000);

begin

  qry := 'select * from test_table where 1=1 ';

  if (item_number is not null) then
    qry := qry || ' and item_number = :1  ';
  else
    qry := qry || ' and (1=1 or :1 is null) ';
  end if;

  if (item_name is not null) then
    qry := qry || ' and item_name = :2 ';
  else
    qry := qry || ' and (1=1 or :2 is null) ';
  end if;

  if (item_col is not null) then
    qry := qry || ' and item_col= :3 ';
  else
    qry := qry || ' and (1=1 or :3 is null) ';
  end if;

  if (item_pol is not null) then
    qry := qry || ' and item_pol = :4 ';
  else
    qry := qry || ' and (1=1 or :4 is null) ';
  end if;

  dbms_output.put_line(qry);

  open res for  qry
    using item_number, item_name, item_col, item_pol;

end;
```

This works because

```
(1=1 or :1 is null)
```

Will always return true (`1=1`), and it still allows you to pass in a bind variable in the correct place. Short circuit evaluation will be triggered so that the optimizer can safely ignore this when working out the best plan.

Comment: That was great ,thanks , could you explain a little bit more about what really happens when we do not supply other input parameters? I mean what happens in this part exactly "and (1=1 or :1 is null)"

Comment: I've edited in an explanation, let me know if it's still not clear

Comment: Thanks , now your answer is completely clear , I'm now a bit confused with about the second answer , I think I have forgot some basic concepts about computer science and some courses we had in our universities , I don't know :D

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be able to call that procedure without supplying all the parameters as you have no defaults.

Comment: You can still call it with `null` as the argument values